# syntax error, unexpected end of file in C:\xampp\htdocs\porto\app\code\Order\Tracking\view\frontend\templates\order\history.phtml on line 73

Tags: magento2

i am getting error in last line

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

/** @var \Magento\Sales\Block\Order\History $block */
/** @var \Order\Tracking\ViewModel\Tracking $trackingModel */

?>
<?php $_orders = $block->getOrders(); ?>
<?php $trackingModel = $block->getData('tracking_view_model'); ?>
<?= $block->getChildHtml('info') ?>
<?php if ($_orders && count($_orders)): ?>
    <div class="table-wrapper orders-history">
        <table class="data table table-order-items history" id="my-orders-table">
            <caption class="table-caption"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Orders') ?></caption>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col" class="col id"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Order #') ?></th>
                    <th scope="col" class="col date"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Date') ?></th>
                    <?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getChildHtml('extra.column.header') ?>
                    <th scope="col" class="col shipping"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Ship To') ?></th>
                    <th scope="col" class="col total"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Order Total') ?></th>
                    <th scope="col" class="col status"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Status') ?></th>
                    <th scope="col" class="col actions"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Action') ?></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <?php foreach ($_orders as $_order): ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Order #')) ?>" class="col id"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_order->getRealOrderId() ?></td>
                        <td data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Date')) ?>" class="col date"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->formatDate($_order->getCreatedAt()) ?></td>
                        <?php $extra = $block->getChildBlock('extra.container'); ?>
                        <?php if ($extra): ?>
                            <?php $extra->setOrder($_order); ?>
                            <?= /* @noEscape */ $extra->getChildHtml() ?>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        <td data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Ship To')) ?>" class="col shipping"><?= $_order->getShippingAddress() ? $block->escapeHtml($_order->getShippingAddress()->getName()) : '&nbsp;' ?></td>
                        <td data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Order Total')) ?>" class="col total"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_order->formatPrice($_order->getGrandTotal()) ?></td>
                        <td data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Status')) ?>" class="col status"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_order->getStatusLabel() ?></td>
                        <td data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Actions')) ?>" class="col actions">
                            <a href="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getViewUrl($_order) ?>" class="action view">
                                <span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('View Order') ?></span>
                            </a>
                            <?php if ($this->helper('Magento\Sales\Helper\Reorder')->canReorder($_order->getEntityId())) : ?>
                                <a href="#" data-post='<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo
                                $this->helper(\Magento\Framework\Data\Helper\PostHelper::class)
                                    ->getPostData($block->getReorderUrl($_order))
                                ?>' class="action order">
                                    <span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Reorder') ?></span>
                                </a>
                            <?php endif ?>
                            <?php if ($_order->getShipmentsCollection()->getSize()): ?>
                                <a href="#"
                                   class="action order"
                                   data-mage-init='{"popupWindow": {"windowURL":"<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $trackingModel->getTrackingPopupUrlBySalesModel($_order) ?>","windowName":"trackorder","width":800,"height":600,"left":0,"top":0,"resizable":1,"scrollbars":1}}'>
                                    <span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Track your order') ?></span>
                                </a>
                            <?php endif ?> 
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <?php if ($block->getPagerHtml()): ?>
        <div class="order-products-toolbar toolbar bottom"><?= $block->getPagerHtml() ?></div>
    <?php endif ?>
<?php else: ?>
    <div class="message info empty"><span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('You have placed no orders.') ?></span></div>
```

Comment: your're missing <?php endif; ?> at the end of your file. add <?php endif; ?> at the end of your template which can resolve your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

missing `<?php endif; ?>` at the end of your file. add `<?php endif; ?>` at the end of your template which can resolve your issue. corrected code below:

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

/** @var \Magento\Sales\Block\Order\History $block */
/** @var \Order\Tracking\ViewModel\Tracking $trackingModel */

?>
<?php $_orders = $block->getOrders(); ?>
<?php $trackingModel = $block->getData('tracking_view_model'); ?>
<?= $block->getChildHtml('info') ?>
<?php if ($_orders && count($_orders)): ?>
    <div class="table-wrapper orders-history">
        <table class="data table table-order-items history" id="my-orders-table">
            <caption class="table-caption"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Orders') ?></caption>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col" class="col id"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Order #') ?></th>
                    <th scope="col" class="col date"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Date') ?></th>
                    <?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getChildHtml('extra.column.header') ?>
                    <th scope="col" class="col shipping"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Ship To') ?></th>
                    <th scope="col" class="col total"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Order Total') ?></th>
                    <th scope="col" class="col status"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Status') ?></th>
                    <th scope="col" class="col actions"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Action') ?></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <?php foreach ($_orders as $_order): ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Order #')) ?>" class="col id"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_order->getRealOrderId() ?></td>
                        <td data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Date')) ?>" class="col date"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->formatDate($_order->getCreatedAt()) ?></td>
                        <?php $extra = $block->getChildBlock('extra.container'); ?>
                        <?php if ($extra): ?>
                            <?php $extra->setOrder($_order); ?>
                            <?= /* @noEscape */ $extra->getChildHtml() ?>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        <td data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Ship To')) ?>" class="col shipping"><?= $_order->getShippingAddress() ? $block->escapeHtml($_order->getShippingAddress()->getName()) : '&nbsp;' ?></td>
                        <td data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Order Total')) ?>" class="col total"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_order->formatPrice($_order->getGrandTotal()) ?></td>
                        <td data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Status')) ?>" class="col status"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_order->getStatusLabel() ?></td>
                        <td data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Actions')) ?>" class="col actions">
                            <a href="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getViewUrl($_order) ?>" class="action view">
                                <span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('View Order') ?></span>
                            </a>
                            <?php if ($this->helper('Magento\Sales\Helper\Reorder')->canReorder($_order->getEntityId())) : ?>
                                <a href="#" data-post='<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo
                                $this->helper(\Magento\Framework\Data\Helper\PostHelper::class)
                                    ->getPostData($block->getReorderUrl($_order))
                                ?>' class="action order">
                                    <span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Reorder') ?></span>
                                </a>
                            <?php endif ?>
                            <?php if ($_order->getShipmentsCollection()->getSize()): ?>
                                <a href="#"
                                   class="action order"
                                   data-mage-init='{"popupWindow": {"windowURL":"<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $trackingModel->getTrackingPopupUrlBySalesModel($_order) ?>","windowName":"trackorder","width":800,"height":600,"left":0,"top":0,"resizable":1,"scrollbars":1}}'>
                                    <span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Track your order') ?></span>
                                </a>
                            <?php endif ?> 
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <?php if ($block->getPagerHtml()): ?>
        <div class="order-products-toolbar toolbar bottom"><?= $block->getPagerHtml() ?></div>
    <?php endif ?>
<?php else: ?>
    <div class="message info empty"><span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('You have placed no orders.') ?></span></div>
<?php endif; ?>
```